# Simple jQuery problem

Tags: jquery, attr, html-table

This one should be easy

I've got this HTML

```
<table class="PageNumbers">
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">text3
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">text
    </td>
    <td>text2
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>moretext
    </td>
    <td>moretext2
    </td>
<td>moretext3
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I need to change the colspan of the first rows first column to one

This is what i've got

```
$('.PageNumbers tr:first td:first').attr('colspan') = '1'
```

Doesn't seem to work though

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Try `colSpan` (note case); dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294850/set-colspan-dynamically-with-jquery

Comment: @Michael Haren Sorry didn't see that one

Comment: no problem, I hope you get it working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're really close I think. Try this.

```
$('.PageNumbers tr:first td:first').attr('colspan', '1');
```

Also, I think by specs class names are supposed to be lowercase? It shouldn't stop anything from working though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.PageNumbers tr:first td:first').attr('colspan', '1');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
$('.PageNumbers')[0].rows[0].cells[0].colSpan = 1;
```

or:

```
$('.PageNumbers')[0].rows[0].cells[0].setAttribute('colSpan', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this selector:

```
$('table.PageNumbers > tr:first > td:first').attr('colspan', '1');
```

[Check out the jQuery selectors for more information :)](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
$('table.PageNumbers').find('tr:first td:first').attr('colspan', '1');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be the fastest.

```
$('.PageNumbers tr td').eq(0).attr('colspan',1);
```