# Make rowspan when cells are identical

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have table like this:

[image]

I want a rowspan in column 'model' when content of cells are identical.

The Table has a filter function, which makes "fixed" colspan not a solution.

I found this same question:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6363/spanning-table-cells-automatically-between-same-value-cells
but sadly doesn't work for me.

Very nice example is also here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1294964/1861097 but for colspan only.

For sorting and filtering I use http://datatables.net

Table can be found here: http://ipt.czechbattlefield.info (switch to Attachments)

Comment: How's the filtering supposed to work afterwards?

Comment: I dont understand, you want to show only distinct items in your table?

Comment: Those icons look like they do unique things - what happens to them when you collapse your rows...?

Comment: I believe you mean `rowspan`.

Comment: Show us the code you use for filtering the table. Of course a cell-spaninng-script will need to be integrated in it. Show us how you have tried to use the scripts you found.

Comment: where is your code? put your code on jsfiddle or codepen

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an example as to how to rowspan any table using jquery.

**Note that the code only works under 1 assumption: The column your wish to rowspan is SORTED**

[You can play with it on Codepen](http://codepen.io/ji_in_coding/pen/YGgwdG?editors=1010)  (try editing indexOfColumnToRowSpan)

JS:

```
$(function(){

  //assumption: the column that you wish to rowspan is sorted.

  //this is where you put in your settings
  var indexOfColumnToRowSpan = 0;
  var $table = $('#myTable');


  //this is the code to do spanning, should work for any table
  var rowSpanMap = {};
  $table.find('tr').each(function(){
    var valueOfTheSpannableCell = $($(this).children('td')[indexOfColumnToRowSpan]).text();
    $($(this).children('td')[indexOfColumnToRowSpan]).attr('data-original-value', valueOfTheSpannableCell);
    rowSpanMap[valueOfTheSpannableCell] = true;
  });

  for(var rowGroup in rowSpanMap){
    var $cellsToSpan = $('td[data-original-value="'+rowGroup+'"]');
    var numberOfRowsToSpan = $cellsToSpan.length;
    $cellsToSpan.each(function(index){
      if(index==0){
        $(this).attr('rowspan', numberOfRowsToSpan);
      }else{
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });
  }

})();
```

html:

```
<table  id="myTable">
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <th align="left">A</th>
     <th align="left">B</th>
     <th align="left">C</th>
     <th align="left">D</th> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Apple</td>
     <td>x</td>
     <td>y</td>
     <td>z</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Apple</td>
     <td>x</td>
     <td>y</td>
     <td>z</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Apple</td>
     <td>x</td>
     <td>y</td>
     <td>z</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Apple</td>
     <td>x</td>
     <td>y</td>
     <td>z</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Apple</td>
     <td>x</td>
     <td>y</td>
     <td>z</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Pear</td>
     <td>x</td>
     <td>y</td>
     <td>z</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Pear</td>
     <td>x</td>
     <td>y</td>
     <td>z</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Pear</td>
     <td>x</td>
     <td>y</td>
     <td>z</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Orange</td>
     <td>x</td>
     <td>y</td>
     <td>z</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Orange</td>
     <td>x</td>
     <td>y</td>
     <td>z</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Orange</td>
     <td>x</td>
     <td>y</td>
     <td>z</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Orange</td>
     <td>x</td>
     <td>y</td>
     <td>z</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Orange</td>
     <td>x</td>
     <td>y</td>
     <td>z</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Orange</td>
     <td>x</td>
     <td>y</td>
     <td>z</td>
   </tr>



</tbody>
</table>
```