# Split rowspan cells in multiple cells using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, wikipedia

Let say I have a table in Wikipedia [Table with rowspan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filemaker#Version_history), I would like to split a rowspan cell into multiple cells underneath and fill with the value from the rowspanned cell.

In the linked table, it would result in 10 new TD which would have "Filemaker, inc." as values.

Since tables are created from top-down left to right, how can I accomplish this using jQuery?

Comment: See this, maybe here is your answer [set colspan dynamically with jquery][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294850/set-colspan-dynamically-with-jquery

Comment: Colspan are easier to manage, since tables are generated top-down left-right. Since I want to do the same but with rowspan, I'm having trouble to conceptualize how to switch "directions".

Comment: Here is a [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brave_(2012_film)#Accolades) to an example. Let say I want to split the cell at right that contains "Pending" into multiple cells with "Pending". How I can do that with jQuery?
_I know how I could manage to do this using pure javascript, but the code would be quite long and painful._

Answer (score 2):

I extended the answer of @vendettamit to support any value of `rowspan`.
It splits on `colspan` too.
And I fixed a bug in it.
http://jsfiddle.net/tcvax28d/38/

*Edit - as a stack snippet*

```js
 function split_rows(tbl_param){
        var tbl = $(tbl_param);
        var tempTable = tbl.clone(true);
    var tableBody = $(tempTable).children();
    $(tableBody).children().each(function(index , item){
        var currentRow = item;
        $(currentRow).children().each(function(index1, item1){
                var rows = $(item1).attr("rowspan");
            if(rows>=2)
            {
                // copy the cell
                var item2 = $(item1).clone(true);
                // Remove rowspan
                $(item1).removeAttr("rowspan");
                $(item2).attr("rowspan",(rows)-1);
                //console.log("item1:",$(item1).text(),", index:",index1);
                // last item's index in next row
                var indexOfLastElement = $(currentRow).next().children().last().index();
                if(indexOfLastElement < index1)
                {
                     $(currentRow).next().append(item2)
                }
                else
                {
                    // intermediate cell insertion
                    $(item2).insertBefore($(currentRow).next().children().eq(index1));
                }
            }
        });
        
    });
        return tempTable;
}
 function split_cols(tbl_param){
        var tbl = $(tbl_param);
        var tempTable = tbl.clone(true);
    var tableBody = $(tempTable).children();
    $(tableBody).children().each(function(index , item){
        var currentRow = item;
        for (var i=0; i<$(currentRow).children().length;i++){
            var item1 = $(currentRow).children().eq(i);
                var cols = $(item1).attr("colspan");
                if(cols>=2)
                {
                    // copy the cell
                    var item2 = $(item1).clone(true);
                    
                    // Remove rowspan
                    $(item1).removeAttr("colspan");
                    $(item2).attr("colspan", cols-1);
                    // last item's index in next row
                    $(item2).insertAfter(item1);
                }
            
        }
        
    });
        return tempTable;
}
function split_tbl(tbl_param){
        var tbl = split_cols(tbl_param);
        tbl = split_rows(tbl);
        return tbl;
}
const res1 = split_tbl($('#tbl'));
$('#test').append(res1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl" border = "1">
    <tr>
        <td>Q</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>O</td>
        <td rowspan="2">C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">D</td>
       
        <td rowspan="2">E</td>
        <td>U</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>G</td>
        <td>U</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>S</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>V</td>
        <td rowspan="3" colspan="2">I</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>T</td>
        <td>K</td>
        <td>W</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">M</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<div id="test"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

see the jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9PZQj/3/

But it's limited to value `rowspan="2"` but you can extend the solution if you like to.