# Javascript Create complex table header from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I want to create a html table header with colspan and i'm lost;
i have this json:

```
var metadata = [{
"colIndex": 0,
    "colType": "String",
    "colName": "PM"
}, {
"colIndex": 1,
    "colType": "String",
    "colName": "PROD"
}, {
"colIndex": 2,
    "colType": "Numeric",
    "colName": "NR/M1"
}, {
"colIndex": 3,
    "colType": "Numeric",
    "colName": "NR/M2"
}, {
"colIndex": 4,
    "colType": "Numeric",
    "colName": "NR/M3"
}, {
"colIndex": 5,
    "colType": "Numeric",
    "colName": "NR/M4"
}, {
"colIndex": 6,
    "colType": "Numeric",
    "colName": "NR/M5"
}, {
"colIndex": 7,
    "colType": "Numeric",
    "colName": "NR ART/M6"
}, {
"colIndex": 8,
    "colType": "Numeric",
    "colName": "NR ART/M1"
}, {
"colIndex": 9,
    "colType": "Numeric",
    "colName": "NR ART/M2"
}, {
"colIndex": 10,
    "colType": "Numeric",
    "colName": "NR ART/M3"
}, {
"colIndex": 11,
    "colType": "Numeric",
    "colName": "NR ART/MX"
}];
```

The table header will be, mostly, based on spliting "colType": "Numeric"

```
+------+-------+-----+--------+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+----+----+----+
|      |       |               NR               |           NR ART          |
+ PAM  | PROD  +-----+--------+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+----+----+----+
|              | M1   | M2    | M3  | M4  | M5  | M6  | M1  | M2  | M3 | MX |
+------+-------+-----+--------+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+----+----+----+
```

First i tried to split colName where colType is numeric

```
var arr = [], a;
$.each(metadata, function (i, v) {
  arr.push(v.colName.split("/"));
  a = v.colName.split("/").length;
});
```

next, i get unique parents (?), but what can i do with this?
i think i must travers this array in hierarchie (parent - children and then to construct the html header).

The array is dynamic.

Any advice? Please and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours i find an answer to my problem.
In this first part i create the tr and th (th non Unique)

```
var a = [], l = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < metadata.length; i++) {
   var d = {
    "colName": metadata[i].colName.split("/"),
        "colType": metadata[i].colType
   };
   a.push(d);
   if (metadata[i].colType == "Numeric") {
      trl = metadata[i].colName.split("/").length;
   }
}
for (var l = 0; l < trl; l++) {
   var tr = $("<tr/>").appendTo("thead");
}

for (var j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
   if (a[j].colType == "String") {
     $("<th/>").addClass("string").attr("rowspan", l).html(a[j].colName).appendTo("thead tr:nth(0)");
   } else {
      for (var k = 0; k < a[j].colName.length; k++) {
          $("<th/>").addClass("numeric").html(a[j].colName[k]).appendTo("thead tr:nth(" + k + ")");
      }
  }
}
```

This part is adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294850/set-colspan-dynamically-with-jquery#8315687).
Now i clean up the table thead living just unique th.

```
$('table tr').each(function () {
  var tr = this;
  var counter = 0;
  var strLookupText = '';

  $('th.numeric', tr).each(function (index, value) {
    var td = $(this);
    if ((td.text() == strLookupText) || (td.text() == "")) {
        counter++;
        td.prev().attr('colspan', '' + parseInt(counter + 1, 10) + '').css({
            textAlign: 'center'
        });
        td.remove();
    } else {
        counter = 0;
    }
    strLookupText = td.text();
   });
});
```

The code it's a litle messy, but it's late.

Answer (score 0):

the below code should do the work please check

```
var arr = {}, a;
$.each(metadata, function (i, v) {
     arr[v.colName.split("/")[0]] = arr[v.colName.split("/")[0]].push(v.colName.split("/")[1]) || [] ;       
});
```

In order to display it

```
for(t1 in arr){
    if(t1.length > 0){
          //has children element
    }
    else{
        //has only 1 element
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing which complicates this, is the need for `colspan` and `rowspan` in your table. So, you need to do a group count on your objects based on the *colName* property.

Here is a crude example of how you could do it. Explanation is in the code comments. (This example uses group count for `colspan`, but `rowspan` is hard-coded. You can do a group-count for `rowspan` as well).

I have used *jQuery* in this example only for creating and adding the table. The core logic is in plain *Javascript*.

***Snippet***:

```js
var metadata = [{"colIndex": 0, "colType": "String", "colName": "PM"}, {"colIndex": 1, "colType": "String", "colName": "PROD"}, {"colIndex": 2, "colType": "Numeric", "colName": "NR/M1"}, {"colIndex": 3, "colType": "Numeric", "colName": "NR/M2"}, {"colIndex": 4, "colType": "Numeric", "colName": "NR/M3"}, {"colIndex": 5, "colType": "Numeric", "colName": "NR/M4"}, {"colIndex": 6, "colType": "Numeric", "colName": "NR/M5"}, {"colIndex": 7, "colType": "Numeric",    "colName": "NR ART/M6"}, {"colIndex": 8, "colType": "Numeric", "colName": "NR ART/M1"}, {"colIndex": 9, "colType": "Numeric", "colName": "NR ART/M2"}, {"colIndex": 10, "colType": "Numeric", "colName": "NR ART/M3"}, {"colIndex": 11, "colType": "Numeric", "colName": "NR ART/MX"}];

// First filtering objects which will form the headers
var rowHeaders = metadata.filter(function(obj) { return obj.colType == "String"; });
var colHeaders = metadata.filter(function(obj) { return obj.colType == "Numeric"; });

// Now we need the grouping on colName with value before slash.
// These will form the group header. Count will determine the colspan.
var colHeadersMain = {};
metadata.forEach(function(obj) { 
    if (obj.colType == "String") { return } // Only for Numeric colType
    // Check if the key has been stored in the colHeadersMain
    if (obj.colName.split('/')[0] in colHeadersMain) {
        // If yes, then increment the value of the key for object colHeadersMain
        colHeadersMain[obj.colName.split('/')[0]]++;
    } else {
        // If not, reset the value
        colHeadersMain[obj.colName.split('/')[0]] = 1;
    }
});

// Variables to hold jQuery elements
var $table = $("<table>"), $thead = $("<thead>"), 
    $row1 = $("<tr>"), $row2 = $("<tr>");

// Iterate row headers and form the first row
// Hard-coding the rowspan. 
// ToDo: Maintain count, similar to column headers.
rowHeaders.forEach(function(obj, idx) {
    var $th = $("<th rowspan='2'>");
    $th.text(obj.colName);
    $row1.append($th);
});

// Iterate col grouping headers and continue the row
// colpsan is the group count that we created earlier
for (var key in colHeadersMain) {
    var $th = $("<th colspan='" + colHeadersMain[key] + "'>");
    $th.text(key);
    $row1.append($th);    
}

// Add the first header row to thead
$thead.append($row1); 

// Iterate next line of col headers 
colHeaders.forEach(function(obj, idx) {
    var $th = $("<th>");
    $th.text(obj.colName.split('/')[1]);
    $row2.append($th);    
});

// Add to the thead
$thead.append($row2); 

// Add to the table
$table.append($thead);

// Add to the page / element
$("#wrap").append($table);

// Done.
```

```css
table, td, th { border: 1px solid gray; border-collapse: collapse; }
th, td { padding: 4px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code, is like @pete code as result, but is almost what i want. See my comment at pete answer.

Comment: @DGA: The only thing hard-coded is the `rowspan` as `2`, which can also be made dynamic the same way `colpsan` has been done. Nothing else is hardcoded. Please explain a little more detail what you are really after.

Comment: 1. the array always have two colType (string and numeric). 2. my example array has colName format as `"colName": " NR/M4"` (spliting by "/" result 2 elements) so i'll have numeric header on two levels, but what if i have `"colName": "NR/M4/OUT"`? The header will have 3 levels(rows) when i split by "/". I so  `$row1 = $("<tr>"), $row2 = $("<tr>");`. This rows also must be dynamic, because in this new case, i'll need to create `$row1 = $("<tr>"), $row2 = $("<tr>");$row3 = $("<tr>");`. Of course, this can be created from `obj.colName.split('/').length`. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Yes. That gets complicated. Maybe a recursive parsing might work, am not too sure.

Answer (score 0):

As you did not tag jQuery in your post, here's a plain-vanilla JavaScript solution (although you did use a `$` in the code of your post, which could indicate jQuery).

The code below, when applied to the `metadata` will parse it into a format that's a little more conducive to what you want to do:

```
var columns = [];
metadata.forEach(function(column, index, array) { // parse into a more friendly format for making columns
    var col = {}, // will be the column
        parts = column.colName.split('/'), // you're splitting on the column name in your post
        match = null, // for lookup, leaving null for falsy test later
        i = 0; // iterator / index
    col.name = parts[0]; // store the name
    col.type = column.colType; // and type
    col.index = column.colIndex; // and index, if you want to use it later
    col.subColumns = []; // make an empty array for any subcolumns that may exist so we can concat later
    if (parts.length > 1) {
        col.subColumns.push({ // subcolumn, push it into the array
            "name": parts[1],
            "index": col.index
        });
    }
    for (i = 0; i < columns.length; i += 1) {
        if (columns[i].name === col.name) { // [parent] column already exists
            match = i; // store the index
            break; // exit the loop
        }
    }
    if (match) { // index found
        columns[i].subColumns = columns[i].subColumns.concat(col.subColumns); // concat the subcolumns
    } else {
        columns.push(col); // did not exist, add it to the array
    }
});
```

Once that's been done, loop through the `columns` variable twice to make your two rows (assumes variables for `thead`, `tr`, and `th` elements).

```
columns.forEach(function(column, index, array) { // loop through once to make "parent" headers
    th = document.createElement('th'); // create th element
    th.colSpan = column.subColumns.length; // set a colSpan as necessary
    if (!column.subColumns.length) { //  if there are no subcolumns, make the header span two rows
        th.rowSpan = 2;
    }
    th.innerText = column.name; // set the header text
    tr.appendChild(th); // add to row
});

columns.forEach(function(column, index, array) { // loop through a second time to get the child headers
    column.subColumns.forEach(function(subColumn, index, array) { // loop through the child headers
        th = document.createElement('th'); // create th
        th.innerText = subColumn.name; // set the header text
        tr.appendChild(th); // add to row
    });
});
```

Here is is in action:

```js
var metadata = [{
        "colIndex": 0,
        "colType": "String",
        "colName": "PM"
    }, {
        "colIndex": 1,
        "colType": "String",
        "colName": "PROD"
    }, {
        "colIndex": 2,
        "colType": "Numeric",
        "colName": "NR/M1"
    }, {
        "colIndex": 3,
        "colType": "Numeric",
        "colName": "NR/M2"
    }, {
        "colIndex": 4,
        "colType": "Numeric",
        "colName": "NR/M3"
    }, {
        "colIndex": 5,
        "colType": "Numeric",
        "colName": "NR/M4"
    }, {
        "colIndex": 6,
        "colType": "Numeric",
        "colName": "NR/M5"
    }, {
        "colIndex": 7,
        "colType": "Numeric",
        "colName": "NR ART/M6"
    }, {
        "colIndex": 8,
        "colType": "Numeric",
        "colName": "NR ART/M1"
    }, {
        "colIndex": 9,
        "colType": "Numeric",
        "colName": "NR ART/M2"
    }, {
        "colIndex": 10,
        "colType": "Numeric",
        "colName": "NR ART/M3"
    }, {
        "colIndex": 11,
        "colType": "Numeric",
        "colName": "NR ART/MX"
    }],
    columns = [],
    thead = document.getElementById('dynamic'), // cache this DOM lookup
    tr = document.createElement('tr'),
    th; // placeholder for th elements that will be created
metadata.forEach(function(column, index, array) { // parse into a more friendly format for making columns
    var col = {}, // will be the column
        parts = column.colName.split('/'), // you're splitting on the column name in your post
        match = null, // for lookup, leaving null for falsy test later
        i = 0; // iterator / index
    col.name = parts[0]; // store the name
    col.type = column.colType; // and type
    col.index = column.colIndex; // and index, if you want to use it later
    col.subColumns = []; // make an empty array for any subcolumns that may exist so we can concat later
    if (parts.length > 1) {
        col.subColumns.push({ // subcolumn, push it into the array
            "name": parts[1],
            "index": col.index
        });
    }
    for (i = 0; i < columns.length; i += 1) {
        if (columns[i].name === col.name) { // [parent] column already exists
            match = i; // store the index
            break; // exit the loop
        }
    }
    if (match) { // index found
        columns[i].subColumns = columns[i].subColumns.concat(col.subColumns); // concat the subcolumns
    } else {
        columns.push(col); // did not exist, add it to the array
    }
});
columns.forEach(function(column, index, array) { // loop through once to make "parent" headers
    th = document.createElement('th'); // create th element
    th.colSpan = column.subColumns.length; // set a colSpan as necessary
    if (!column.subColumns.length) { //  if there are no subcolumns, make the header span two rows
        th.rowSpan = 2;
    }
    th.innerText = column.name; // set the header text
    tr.appendChild(th); // add to row
});
thead.appendChild(tr); // add row to thead
tr = document.createElement('tr'); // reset row
columns.forEach(function(column, index, array) { // loop through a second time to get the child headers
    column.subColumns.forEach(function(subColumn, index, array) { // loop through the child headers
        th = document.createElement('th'); // create th
        th.innerText = subColumn.name; // set the header text
        tr.appendChild(th); // add to row
    });
});
thead.appendChild(tr); // add row to thead
```

```css
th {border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead id="dynamic"></thead>
</table>
```

jQuery, if you're using it, can make this syntax a little more "sugary" (mostly in making the rows and header cells, see below), but the principle will be the same.

```
columns.forEach(function(column, index, array) { // loop through once to make "parent" headers
    th.clone().attr({
        "colSpan": column.subColumns.length,
        "rowSpan": column.subColumns.length === 0 ? 2 : 1
    }).text(column.name).appendTo(tr);
});
tr.appendTo(thead);
tr = $('<tr />');
columns.forEach(function(column, index, array) { // loop through a second time to get the child headers
    column.subColumns.forEach(function(subColumn, index, array) { // loop through the child headers
        th.clone().text(subColumn.name).appendTo(tr);
    });
});
tr.appendTo(thead);
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code, is like @abhitalks code  as result, but is almost what i want. For this array (with 2 levels) it's ok to hardcode the levels, but i said the array is dinamic. Was my fault, because i didn't specified that is horizontal and vertical. Horizontal is OK, because the tabel is created for first two levels (my array) with all columns. I'll study both your codes to learn and to adapt at my needs.