# jQuery DataTables rowspan and colspan

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Is there a way to use `rowspan` and `colspan` in jQuery DataTables, when building the table from JavaScript (I saw [this](https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html) example, but the table is hardcoded in HTML)?

Comment: What do you want to do that the DataTables link doesn't show you?

Comment: I have dynamic data and also columns, and I want to add colspan for the first column hedaers, also the colspan number is configurable

Comment: So you want to add columns dynamically?

Comment: "colspan" dynamically

Comment: You're looking at a jQuery solution.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294850/set-colspan-dynamically-with-jquery or post your code here

Comment: I know about this solution, but I wanted to do somehow through configuration